# Control page title in Angular environment

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I know that has been asked many times. Practically any solution works 100% fine in Chrome, but IE is something else. Here is a very simple code that I am using:
Main page:

```
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
```

controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
     //$window.document.title = 'Prism Main';
     $rootScope.title = 'Main Page';
 });
```

IE puts: Main Page#/StateName

Any idea why it's not working in IE?

Thanks

Comment: seems to work for me in IE-11

Answer (score 0):

You could define controller at the  level.

```
 <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="titleCtrl">
   <head>
     <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
```

...
You create service: Page and modify from controllers.

```
myModule.factory('Page', function() {
   var title = 'default';
   return {
     title: function() { return title; },
     setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
   };
});
```

Inject Page and Call 'Page.setTitle()' from controllers.

Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0e7T6l?p=preview

Comment: I think it will come up with {{ Page.title() }} before a state is changed.

Comment: ya you need to call this service from all controllers... so you can get it custom..

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in a way that is works across browsers.

You may want to create a directive that you can just put in your pages: `<some-element page-title="My Page Title"></some-element>` or use a service. I will demonstrate a simple service.

```
PageTitle.$inject = ['$document'];
function PageTitle($document) { this.$document = $document }
PageTitle.prototype.setPageTitle = function(title) {
    this.$document.title = title;
}

app.service('pageTitle', PageTitle);
```

Then somewhere else you have this service injected and you use it simply as:

```
pageTitle.setPageTitle("Foo");
```